# VAAPI Compatibility issue with "Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller"

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, intel, vaapi, intel-media-sdk

i am getting below error while running *vainfo*

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.99.0 libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'iHD' libva info: Trying to open /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_32 
libva error: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/iHD_drv_video.so init failed 
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1 vaInitialize failed with error code 1 (operation failed),exit
```

This is happening after installing *Intel Media Server Studio 2017* ([see](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-setup-media-server-studio-on-secondary-os-of-linux)), before that vainfo was working fine, as i installed below packages and drivers, suggested from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240386/how-do-i-enable-hardware-accelerated-video-in-vlc-with-intel-hd-4000-gpu).

`sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver libva-intel-vaapi-driver vainfo`

```
Machine configuration : ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Processor : Intel i7(i7-3720QM)
Graphics  : Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
```

Is this just because Intel SDK does not support 3rd Generation Processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with version of *Media SDK* used, *Media SDK-2017* supports only *4th/5th Generation Processors*.

For *3rd Generation Machine Media SDK-2015-R1* is the compatible version, which can be downloaded from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/media-sdk). Using the correct version with corresponding hardware will solve this problem.